# Azure Python function Service Bus outbound attribute

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a azure python function : It gets triggered by HTTP , responds with  HTTP response and puts the message in the Azure Service Bus Queue.

Function.json: for outbound Azure Service bus

```
{
    "type": "serviceBus",
    "connection": "ServiceBus",
    "name": "outputMessage",
    "queueName": "testqueue",
    "accessRights": "send",
    "direction": "out"
    }
```

I have function as

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, outputMessage:  func.Out[func.ServiceBusMessage]) -> str:
```

I get below error:
Result: Failure
Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the HttpTrg function: type of outputMessage binding in function.json "serviceBus" does not match its Python annotation "ServiceBusMessage"

Question:
1. What should be the python annotation for Azure Service Bus outbound ?

```
def main( , outputMessage:  func.Out[func.ServiceBusMessage])
```

2. Can I keep -> str for Azure Service Bus ?

   func.Out[func.ServiceBusMessage]) -> str
3. Can i use the set method to send message like :

   outputMessage.set(text)

"To produce multiple outputs, use the set() method provided by the azure.functions.Out interface to assign a value to the binding"  -> will this work?

Thanks
Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/447) of being able to do output binding to service bus with python:

```
// function.json

{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsServiceBusConnectionString",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "outqueue"
    }
  ]
}
```

.

```
# __init__.py

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:

    msg.set(req.get_body())

    return 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say  *Azure Service Queue* you probably mean  *Azure Storage Queue*.

The binding `serviceBus` is specifically for Service Bus, not Storage Queues.

You need to use `queueName`.

Here's an example of output binding. Firstly, we have the `function.json` file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
  {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now we can use it like so:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[func.QueueMessage]) -> str:

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        msg.set(name)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
            status_code=400
        )
```

**Output Binding with Python to Service Bus**

Here's your `function.json` code:

```
{
    "name": "outputSbQueue",
    "type": "serviceBus",
    "queueName": "testqueue",
    "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
    "direction": "out"
}
```

Also, the following references may be helpful for you:

[Azure Function - Python - ServiceBus Output Binding - Setting Custom Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657209/azure-function-python-servicebus-output-binding-setting-custom-properties)
https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/quickstart-v2-python-functions.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/taking-a-closer-look-at-python-support-for-azure-functions/

https://unofficialism.info/posts/quick-start-with-azure-function-v2-python-preview/

**Sending messages to service bus queue [without an explicit binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues)**

```
from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message

# Create the QueueClient
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(
    "<CONNECTION STRING>", "<QUEUE NAME>")

# Send a test message to the queue
msg = Message(b'Test Message')
queue_client.send(msg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , my  bad : I am trying to post a message to Azure Service Bus Queue . I should have mentioned Service Bus , Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions for Azure Service Bus queue Outbound attribute?

Comment: i've updated my answer and added a few things, but havent been able to find output binding in python to servicebus queue ---- have you considered storage queues? any reason why you dont want to use storage queues?

Comment: Thanks,  We have an existing application ( not Azure function )  which produces  messages  to Azure Service Bus .  So we need a Azure function to read the message update/transform the message and put it back to Azure Service Bus queue  ( different queue ) .  What I have tried  is slightly different HTTPTrigger -> Azure Service Bus queue ( just for understanding how azure python functions can send messages to Azure Service Bus )

Comment: i dont know if you are aware, but you dont need to have a binding in order to be able to use servicebus. the binding is just a short way of doing it.

Comment: check my updated answer, ive included a snippet of code that allows you to write to a queue

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that we don't need binding in order to use service bus,  will try that.

Comment: please keep me updated, id be very curious to know your status

Comment: Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.servicebus'

Comment: File "/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTrg/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message

Comment: `pip install azure-servicebus`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Azure ServiceBusMessage class as an outbound parameter is not supported:

> Attributes are not supported by Python.
> Use the Azure Service Bus SDK rather than the built-in output binding.

[Azure Service Bus output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python)

ServiceBusMessage can only be used for Trigger binding:

```
import azure.functions as func
def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
```

> The queue message is available to the function via a parameter typed as func.ServiceBusMessage. The Service Bus message is passed into the function as either a string or JSON object.

[Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python#example)