# Is it possible to add or define user or custom properties for service bus topic message in azure function app code in python

Tags: python, filter, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Currently we are working with python azure function service bus topic trigger

Our case is we have one topic and in that we have 3 subscriptions , So we want to send the mgs to particular subscription that why is have add sql filter to that subscription

So when we send mgs in azure portal service bus with custom properties its working

No we need to add the custom properties in azure function service bus topic trigger python code So that we Only send mgs from service bus without any custom properties in portal because the property will be add already in function app code and the mgs will be sent to that particular subscription has the filter condition satisfy.

We are trying to add custom properties but couldn't find a way. Is there any other way or you mention that sender needs to set custom property right any Idea how to set custom property in azure function app python code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is how to add custom properties to a service bus topic with python code you can do it like this:

```
 with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING"]) as servicebus_client:
            with servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name="first_topic_service_bus") as sender:
                    servicebus_message = ServiceBusMessage(data)
                    servicebus_message.application_properties = {
                          "property1": "value1",
                          "property2": "value2",
                          "property3": "value3"
                    }
                    sender.send_messages(servicebus_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [service bus output binding document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) I don't see you can set the custom property on the message. Alternatively, rather than using the service bus output binding you can leverage the Azure Service bus python SDK to send the message using your custom property.

Sharing the [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657209/azure-function-python-servicebus-output-binding-setting-custom-properties) and [custom code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562530/13796136) leveraging the SDK to send the message.